# ASP.NET include behavior

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, include, conditional-statements

What happens if I include 2 pages conditionally?

```
<% if(x==1) {%>
<!-- #Include virtual="/ws/inc/Master1.inc" -->
<% } else { %>
<!-- #Include virtual="/ws/inc/Master2.inc" -->
<% } %>
```

Which command runs first? Are both included at first, and then the `if` clause is evaluated, or will just one of them be included?

I want to be sure not to include the wrong page at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the condition. If you don't have the statement inside a loop where you iterate through `x` or something similar, I think only one page will be included depending on the value of `x`